# Getting DRBD to boot up in a synchronized state from cold boot

Tags: lvm, cluster, drbd, embedded-linux, gfs2

I am working in an environment with an embedded High-Availability NVMeoF cluster, and need this cluster to be available within minutes of a cold power-on of all nodes, and trying to set up a RAID-10 on this cluster.

The legacy infrastructure that I am working with is based on GFS2 and LVM2. Unfortunately, the raid-10 option for LVM appears to only allow one journal for GFS2, when I need more. I started working down the path of manually setting up a series of RAID-1 arrays with DRBD over which I could set up a RAID-0 with LVM2. I have been able to set this up without too much trouble. However, at this point, I run into a snag: How do I cleanly shut down and start back up the nodes for seamless data transition?

My initial, basic attempts have resulted in each board booting in a state with synchronization at 0%, and it takes hours for them to resync. I used the following commands on each of four nodes to attempt to shut down cleanly:

```
vgchange -a n g1 #g1 is the logical volume laid overtop the physical volumes of r0 and r1
vgchange --lockstop

drbdadm down r0 #drbd resource configured as a physical volume
drbdadm down r1 #drbd resource configured as a physical volume
```

Then each board is power cycled, and I attempt to start back up with the following commands:

```
drbdadm up r0
drbdadm up r1
if [ `hostname` = "appropriate-host" ]; then drbdadm primary --force r0; fi
if [ `hostname` = "appropriate-host2" ]; then drbdadm primary --force r1; fi
vgchange --lockstart
vgchange -asy g1
```

I have noticed that sometimes, this just works. Other times, I am told that my metadata is invalid and I will need to recreate it. After running drbdadm create-md r0 or r1, synchronization via drbd occurs from a 0% starting point, which takes hours, which my effort can't sustain. I am unsure if a specific start-up/shut-down sequence might allow me to reliably avoid synchronization concerns; if there is a way to force DRBD to speed up re-synchronization efforts; if swapping to a RAID-01 configuration where DRBD is overlaid on top of two logical volumes might ensure a more reliable starting configuration that can skip initial synchronization; or if I'm using entirely the wrong tools for the job.

Does ServerOverflow have any insight to help me tool up my configuration for reliable and clean start-ups and shut-downs? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like overcomplicated setup. Have you considered using Starwinds VSAN instead of DRBD to get rid of those resyncs and issues? As far as I know they have a free Linux version of their product that supports RAID and LVM fully and started working towards NVMeoF features, so it is definitely worth talking to them.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free